# SQL Floating Point Error with IRR Calculation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, finance, irr

I had a coworker that wrote an IRR calculation function. You supply what seems to be set of cash flows, and it returns the IRR.  It works 99% of the time but sometimes I get a floating point error. I am trying to figure out where in the code that can happen.  The function looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CalcXIRR]
(
    @Sample XIRRTable READONLY,
    @Rate FLOAT = 0.1
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(38, 9)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @X FLOAT = 0.0,
    @X0 FLOAT = 0.1,
    @f FLOAT = 0.0,
    @fbar FLOAT = 0.0,
    @i TINYINT = 0,
    @found TINYINT = 0

    IF @Rate IS NULL
        SET @Rate = 0.1

    SET @X0 = @Rate

    WHILE @i < 100
    BEGIN

        SELECT  @f = 0.0, 
                @fbar = 0.0

        SELECT  @f = @f + value * POWER(1 + @X0, (-theDelta / 365.0E)),
                @fbar = @fbar - theDelta / 365.0E * value * POWER(1 + @X0, (-theDelta / 365.0E - 1))
        
        FROM    
        (
            SELECT  Value,
                    DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(date) OVER (), date) AS theDelta

            FROM    @Sample

        ) AS d

        SET @X = @X0 - @f / @fbar

        IF ABS(@X - @X0) < 0.00000001
        BEGIN
            SET @found = 1
            BREAK;
        END

        SET @X0 = @X
        SET @i += 1

    END

    IF @found = 1
        RETURN  @X

    RETURN NULL
END
GO
```

You supply it data that looks like this:

```
Date                     Value
2017-08-01 00:00:00.000 -3775585
2017-08-01 00:00:00.000 -10763.73
2017-08-01 00:00:00.000 -10763.73
2017-08-01 00:00:00.000 10763.73
2017-08-01 00:00:00.000 10763.73
2017-08-01 00:00:00.000 3775585
2017-08-01 00:00:00.000 3786348.73
2017-08-02 00:00:00.000 -1550780
2017-08-02 00:00:00.000 -4823
2017-08-02 00:00:00.000 -4823
2017-09-11 00:00:00.000 -254800
2017-09-11 00:00:00.000 254800
```

Comment: Provide an example of the data that generates the error.  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason not to use decimal instead of float?

See [this link](https://bertwagner.com/2019/10/01/more-wrong-sql-server-math-floating-point-errors/) from Bert Wagner.

Here is an excerpt from it:

> Floating point math errors can be fixed in a few ways.
>
> One option is to stop caring about them. The error occurring on floats
> is very small (although when compounded through arithmetic, the error
> can grow large enough to be noticeable like in my reporting bar chart
> example). If you are writing queries or reports where such a small
> amount of error doesn’t matter, then you can continue on your merry
> way without having to change anything.
>
> A second option is to still store values as floats (for that sweet,
> sweet storage space savings), but ensure your application code has
> business logic to correctly round numbers that are in precise.
>
> However, if your data needs to be perfectly accurate every single time
> with no errors, use a different datatype. The logical choice here
> would be to use decimal in SQL Server, which uses a different internal
> method for storing your numbers, resulting in perfect results every
> time. However, the range of possible values is not as large as float,
> and you will pay for that precision with additional bytes of storage
> space.
>
> In the end, floating point is good enough for many applications. The
> important thing is that you are aware that these kind of errors can
> happen and that you handle them appropriately.